# Error with addEventListener on click for calculator exercise

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm a  beginner in JS, just got the template of a calculator in HTML and I'm trying to build its functionalities through JS. I'm starting with the addition button initially.

I wrote the code below, however, I keep getting this error on the browser console: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at script.js.9:9*

Could anyone please advise?

```
const a = Number(document.getElementById('num1'));
const b = Number(document.getElementById('num2'));

const btnSoma = document.querySelector('.add');

//sum
btnSoma.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const soma = a + b;
  console.log(soma);
});
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora Simples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Número 1">
        <input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="Número 2">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button onclick="add()">+</button>
            <button onclick="subtract()">-</button>
            <button onclick="multiply()">*</button>
            <button onclick="divide()">/</button>
        </div>
        <p id="result">Resultado: </p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML? it seems you don't have a button with the `add` class on it.

Comment: When get that fixed, you can't expect number conversion to work with elements, you've to convert the value/textContent of the elements instead.

Comment: Hi Aashutosh. Shared it. Thank you.

Comment: `const btnSoma = document.querySelector('.add');` <-- I don't see anything in your HTML with a class of `add` and so the line returns `undefined` and therefore there is nothing to use `.addEventListener()` with.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks. How could I select the add button from HTML to work with it on the JavaScript file?

Comment: Add `class="add"` to the button's HTML. `<button class="add" onclick="add()">`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the script is executed before the HTML has finished loading. To solve this issue, you should ensure that your script runs after the DOM has loaded.

One way to do this is by placing your script at the end of the body tag, just before the closing  tag, or by wrapping your code in an event listener for the DOMContentLoaded event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const btnSoma = document.querySelector('.add');

            btnSoma.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const a = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
                const b = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value);
                const soma = a + b;
                console.log(soma);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. What worked was to call a function in JS with the same name of the onclick button, this way I could have a code triggered in JS for as soon as the + button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found an answer, at least here it's working perfectly: to access a onclick button from HTML in a JavaScript file, one can simply use *function* and name it the same as the onclick.
In the thread example, `function add() {}`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select an element with the class `.add`, which doesnt exist.

Instead of using onClick on each button do this: `class="add"` - for the add Button. Now do the same for the other buttons with substract, …

Comment: Thanks. That does make sense and I implemented this change you proposed, however, afterwards I got another error message: "Uncaught TypeError: add is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14:42)". What worked instead was to call a function in JS with the same name of the onclick button, this way I could have a code triggered in JS for as soon as the + button is clicked.

Comment: @AngeloBorsato yes thats also a way to do it :)